# SharePoint Sandbox 2010 on Office 365 - list workflow only start for the first 6 items after inserted programmatically

Tags: list, workflow, sandbox-solution, office-365

I'm inserting x numbers of items into a list programmatically. On this list I have a list-workflow which starts when an item is created.

The problem is that if I insert more than 6 items at one time the workflow only starts for the first 6 items in the list. The rest of the items the workflow doesn't even start.

Have anyone ever experienced this before and have anyone found a solution to this.

**PLEASE NOTE**: *I'm running a Sandbox solution on Office 365 so I can not modify the web.config file or install any updates.*

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get this to work (consulting with Microsoft as well) was to have a site workflow which starts the list workflow - one by one. Because sandbox solutions have a 30 seconds timeout on custom code workflows activities I would have to cancel the workflow before the 30 second timeout occur and then restart the site workflow.